# Angularjs boolean return value to controller behavior

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

I'm newbie to angularjs and i try to get asp.net web api to work with angularjs.

For testing, my domain webapi will always send a false value to angular Checkdomain and assign it to $scope.domainValid

```
$scope.checkDomain = function (domain, tld) {    

        $http.get(checkdomainUrl)
        .success(function (data) {

            $scope.domainValid = data;  >> view shows up when i hard code $scope.domainValid=false;
        })
        .error(function (error) {              

        });

    }
```

On my view:

```
    {{domainValid}}  >> always show correct value(false), so the data return from webapi works
<div class="dkExistingInfo" ng-show="!domainValid && domainValid!=null">
    <span>Tên miền {{newDomain}} đã có người đăng ký. Vui lòng chọn tên khác</span>
</div>
```

Why div class="dkExistingInfo" never shows up with $scope.domainValid = data; but works with $scope.domainValid = false;

What happened to my controller/view?

Comment: Check if your variable type data. Its string not boolean?

Comment: i guess the webapi returns (false) as string in json format. Thanks.

Comment: Added answer check it

Answer (score 0):

Return data variable is type of string not a boolean.

**Approach:**

1. Convert your variable to boolean on success in controller.

   ```
   data = (data === 'true') ? true : false;
   $scope.domainValid = data;
   ```

**OR**

2. You have to check it as a string in angular js view. For this use **[ng-If](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)** directive:

   ```
   <div ng-if == "domainValid == 'true'">
        <!-- Your code -->
   </div>
   <div ng-if == "domainValid == 'false'">
      <!-- Your code -->
   </div>
   ```